# Alternate to tkinter text box (inserting StringVar)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am very new to python (coding at all for that matter) and and this website.  I am making a small Dice Roll program and I wish to display the results of each roll inside a text box (entry or label) as a sort of 'Roll History'.  I am a very visual oriented learner, and though I have my code I thought it would be easier for me to convey my question via a visual representation as I do not yet have the language to ask the specific question, so here goes:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkP5T.jpg

I have tried using a text box, an entry, and a label.  I have searched and found a few people saying that what I am trying to do cannot be done with tkinter text boxes.  I was able to do it to a very limited degree with a label textvariable, however I wasn't able to add multiple textvariables (one for each die) or have multiple lines of the same die.

Therefore, my question is, is this even possible with tkinter widgets, or should I go about this via a different route such as different GUI framework?

I'm sorry this is probably a very vague or abstract question, but any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
from random import randrange
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def click():
    D20roll.set(randrange(1,21))
    D4roll.set('')
    D6roll.set('')
    D8roll.set('')
    D10roll.set('')
    D12roll.set('')
    D100roll.set('')

D20roll = StringVar()

DR = tk.Tk()

d20button = tk.Button(DR, command=click)
d20label = tk.Label(DR, textvariable=D20roll)
history = tk.Label(DR, bg="#525252", textvariable=D20roll)

DR.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is very possible with a Label widget, but do you wish to add the text in the same Label or create a new one with every roll? Though the image says what you're trying to achieve , sharing some code would greatly help readers understand what you've tried so far.

Comment: I wish to be able to clear the lines once they have filled up the area. Would that be easier with one label? My code is likely fairly messy and the code i have put in the OP will not run as I just threw together the pieces of interest, if you need more let me know, thanks for quick reply!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I wish to print each roll on a new line, until it fills up the area.  Sorry again for the ambiguity, I'm not very good at asking the right question!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a listbox in Tkinter to add as many items as you want

```
lb=Tk.Listbox(DR)
lb.insert(1,first_result)
lb.insert(2,second_result)
```

you can use insert in a loop, you can also delete previous entries if you only want a number of history displayed.

Edit: your complete code would be something like this:

```
from random import randrange
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def click(history_listbox):
    D20roll.set(randrange(1,21))
    D4roll.set('')
    D6roll.set('')
    D8roll.set('')
    D10roll.set('')
    D12roll.set('')
    D100roll.set('')
    #do something with the history_listbox

D20roll = StringVar()

DR = tk.Tk()

d20label = tk.Label(DR, textvariable=D20roll)
history = tk.Listbox(DR)
d20button = tk.Button(DR, command=click, args=(history,)

DR.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that is probably exactly the widget I needed! I am going to try it, does that mean that in order to insert the line into the listbox when I click the button, that I need to move my button click definition into the mainloop?

Comment: my way would be to make a class for your GUI, then use the click as a method of class, that way the listbox will be a variable inside the class and you can freely use it. If you are unfamilier with the class, try to pass the listbox to your click function, python passes by reference, so you can use llb.insert() inside your function. Don't include in mainloop()

Comment: Great! I got it working just how I want it with the listbox!  I simply had to add ```history.insert(END, D20roll.get())```  I just simply wasn't using the ```insert``` method correctly.  Now I just need to be able to clear the entire listbox once it fills up with rolls.  I used ```.delete``` but it deletes one at a time.  I tried ```selection_set``` and then ```selection_clear```, but that is not working.  Anyhow, you have answered my question by suggesting the listbox! Thanks again!

Comment: `history.delete(0,END)` will delete all your rolls at once.